# Included HTML form is inaccessible by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, include

I have 2 files, one is index.php and the other is called user.php.

Based on a set of conditions in index.php I call this method once:

```
include "pages/user.php";
```

The page user.php contains some HTML code and the following:

```
<form action="php/activity.php" method="POST">
    What was done:<br />
    <textarea name="done" rows="15" cols="30"></textarea><br /><br />

    <input type="hidden" id="activitydoneid" name="activity_id" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="finish" />

    <input type="submit" value="Finish activity" />
</form>
```

As you can see I have 2 hidden inputs. For the first one, the one with the id "activitydoneid" I need a value. For that I have the following javascript function.

```
function done_activity(id)
{
    center_div('done_activity_dialog');

    var elem = document.getElementById('activitydoneid');
    elem.value = id;
}
```

If I manually copy-paste the code from user.php in the index.php file the input gets its value assigned.

If I try to include the whole user.php file using "include" the input has no value.

My question is this: can I somehow fix this?

Comment: can you see the html from pages/user.php in the source when you load the whole page?

Comment: The include "pages/user.php" is equivalent to copy-pasting it, so that problem is somewhere else.

Comment: where exactly are you including the file? and have you checked if your conditions to include the file are fullfilled?  so did you check the html sourcecode to see if the file actually has been included by php?

Comment: As @bobdye said, when php is parsing the file, it will copy and insert the file on that line. And the javascript seems to be correct from what you've posted here. So you're either not calling javascript correctly, or you're including user.php incorrectly. It's hard to tell with just this code.

Comment: The rest of the user.php page shows up just fine. The function is called when a user presses a button on that page, so the file is loaded.